# Laravel Error "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'os' cannot be null"

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, checkbox

When im input using checkbox for value windows 7 & 10 it doesn't get into the database.

But input in part <-- other -->, it can enter into database

Views Code :

```
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
    <label>OS :</label>
    <div class="checkbox-list">
        <label class="form-group col-md-4">
            <input id="os" name="os" type="radio" value="Windows 7">
            <span></span>
            Windows 7
        </label>
        <label class="form-group col-md-4">
            <input id="os" name="os" type="radio" class="form-group" value="Windows 10">
            <span></span>
            Windows 10
        </label>


        <!-- other -->  
        <label>                                 
            <input id="other" name="" type="radio" class="form-group" value="Other :">
            <label for="other" class="form-group">Other :</label>

            <div class="other-disclosure">
                <input type="text" name="os" id="os-other" class="form-group col-md-2" placeholder="Your OS ...">
            </div>
        </label>
        <!-- other -->

    </div>
</div>
```

Controller Code:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $folderPath = public_path('assets/signature/');
    $image_parts = explode(";base64,", $request->signed);
    $image_type_aux = explode("image/", $image_parts[0]);
    $image_type = $image_type_aux[1];
    $image_base64 = base64_decode($image_parts[1]);
    $signature = uniqid() . '.'.$image_type;
    $file = $folderPath . $signature;
    file_put_contents($file, $image_base64);

    auth()->user()->Form003()->create
    ([
        'user_id' => $request->user_id,
        'os' => $request->os,
        'hardware' => implode(',', (array) $request->input('hardware', [])),
        'software' => $request->software,
        'signature' => $signature,
        'status_desc' => $request->status_desc,
        'cancel_deskripsi' => $request->cancel_deskripsi
    ]);

    // dd($request->all())
    // dd($form003);
    
    return redirect()->route('form003')->with('status', 'Success');
}
```

even though they are one group

How to solve this problem ?

===========================================================================
its work, i change the input name

```
<label>                                 
    <!-- <input id="other" name="os" type="radio" class="form-group" value="Other :">
     -->
    <input id="other" name="os" type="radio" class="form-group" type="text">
    <label for="other" class="form-group">Other :</label>

    <div class="other-disclosure">
        <input type="text" name="other" id="os-other" class="form-group col-md-2" placeholder="Isi OS Anda ...">
    </div>
</label>
```

but input with "other" get new problem,
the value that goes into the database always "on", not based on what i write the text.

the value "on" comes from where ?

Comment: Probably because you have the same name on input. So when the form gets submitted it contains the value of the input which occurs last in case of inputs with same name. Try changing the name of input in other as say name="other-os" and check

Comment: Make sure you added `os` on model's fillable property

Comment: Pls don't post code in comments it difficult to read. You can edit your question with a note or update heading and include the code below it for better readability.